# Handling multiple form inputs in one method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a component:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ControlLabel, Form, FormControl, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

export interface IGiftState {
  person: string;
  present: string;
}

class Gift extends React.Component<{}, IGiftState> {
  public state = {
    person: '',
    present: ''
  };

  public handleChange = (event: any): void => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <ControlLabel>Person</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              name="person"
              className="input-person"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <ControlLabel>Present</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              name="present"
              className="input-present"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Gift;
```

I am using html5 "name" attribute for inputs just to reuse the "handleChange" method. Then I want to change the state property of the same name but Typescript throws an error:

```
(16,19): Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGiftState | ((prevState: Readonly<IGiftState>, props: {}) => IGiftState | Pick<IGiftState, "pers...'.
```

Type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick'.
    Property 'person' is missing in type '{ [x: number]: any; }'.

Only way around that is make two methods (i.e. handlePersonInput and handlePresentInput) and hardcode changing state for those properties. However, that is not very DRY code. How do I work this out?

Comment: Does `this.setState({ [event.target.name as any]: event.target.value });` work for you? `this.setState({ [event.target.name as keyof IGiftState]: event.target.value });` might also work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've tried both of them and the error persists

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not supplying the value prop for the FormControl.

Add:

```
value = {this.state.person}
```